# How do I push text into an array? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

This is for a CodeAcademy javascript course. I'm kind of stuck on this, and not sure how to proceed.

I need to be able to search for the name "Alex" in the "text" variable. Then I need the 2nd For Loop to push the letters into the "hits" array.

```
     /*jshint multistr:true */
 var text = "My name is Alex. What is yours? Again, my name is Alex";
 var myName = "Alex";
 var hits = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ){

 if(i === text["A"]){


 for(var j = i;  i + myName.length; i++){

    hits.push("Alex");}

 }


   }
```

Comment: As a hint, look up the indexOf function that all javascript strings come with
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the string, then you can either use that with [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) on the array or with push.[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) on the array

Comment: You are iterating the entire `text` string one letter at a time. `i` is a number `if(i === text["A"]){` should not match `"A"`.  `text["A"]` does not get an index of `text` string. `text[i] === "A"`  There is no condition at second `for` loop. If you only match `"A"` you will also match `"A"` at `"Again"` if you do not `break` loop.

Comment: These are the instructions for this particular section. "Okay! Last loopy step: add another for loop, this time inside the body of your if statement (between the if's {}s).

This loop will make sure each character of your name gets pushed to the final array. The if statement says: "If we find the first letter of the name, start the second for loop!" This loop says: "I'm going to add characters to the array until I hit the length of the user's name." So if your name is 11 letters long, your loop should add 11 characters to hits if it ever sees the first letter of myName in text."

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the entire `text` string one letter at a time. `i` is a number `if(i === text["A"]){` should not match `"A"`. `text["A"]` does not get an index of `text` string. Use `text[i] === "A"`. There is no condition at second for loop `i + myName.length`; substitute `j < i + myName.length`. If you only match "A" you will also match "A" at "Again" if you do not `break` outer `for` loop.

Note that currently, there is no check that first match of `"A"` is followed by `"lex"` followed by a space `" "` character.

You can alternatively use `.split()` or `.match()` to get an array of all words in `text`, the iterate the words, check for match of `myName`.

```js
var text = "My name is Alex. What is yours? Again, my name is Alex";
var myName = "Alex";
var hits = [];

outer: for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text[i] === "A") {   
    for (var j = i; j < i + myName.length; j++) {
      hits.push(text[j]);
    }
    break outer;
  }
}

console.log(hits);
```